# Nature of the sample

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, statistical-finance

When we calculate a difference between the market price and modelled price. so to test the significance whether we apply dependent test or independent test.

Comment: +1 for noob2 guessing the intent but this question is not well-stated (and would probably fit better on CrossValidated).

Answer (score 1):

When you compare each market price to a model price calculated under corresponding assumptions (regarding underlying price, time to maturity, etc.) you have a paired sample (also called dependent sample).